# Использование GraphQL в ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, graphql

Начал изучение GraphQL делал относительно всё по примерам, но почему-то сервер не отвечает и я постоянно получаю ошибку 500 не понимаю что я не правильно делаю, я оставлю тут [ссылку на проект в github](https://github.com/Ethernets/GraphQLTestv), помогите пожалуйста понять где я допустил ошибку. Спасибо

Comment: Уточните: ваш проект asp.net или asp.net core? Это _разные_ технологии.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov asp.net-core видимо я увлёкся метками